# How to detect kill of my process?

Tags: c, linux

I want to detect the kill signal of my program inorder to execute some C instruction before leaving my program. my program is running on linux

Is it possible to do that? If yes how I can do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can register a [*signal handler*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_handler#Handling_signals) using `sigaction()`.  Note that you cannot handle `SIGKILL` or `SIGSTOP` though.

Comment: While this is completely correct, giving a link as an answer was, I thought, frowned on on this forum.

Comment: @jimmcnamara: My answer is a tiny bit more than just a link ;)  (I can't be bothered to write an entire code snippet, unless the OP explicitly asks for one...)

Answer (score 1):

No, SIGKILL can not be handled, maybe you want to catch CTRL+C, then:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t stop;

void
inthand(int signum)
{
    stop = 1;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    signal(SIGINT, inthand);

    while (!stop)
        printf("a");

    printf("exiting safely\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Will do the trick

Comment: Please don't use `signal`; it's unportable and arguably deprecated. `sigaction` provides a cleaner way of dealing with signals.

Answer (score -1):

If SIGKILL or SIGTERM  is sent to your process you cannot mask or ignore the signal. Other signals you can handle and mask it.

Comment: my goal is not to ignore kill signal, my goal is to execute some C functions before leaving my program

Comment: You can very well do it if you write a signal handler. But for SIGKILL and SIGTERM you cant use this logic

Comment: It's not `SIGTERM` but `SIGSTOP` that can not be caught.

Comment: "my goal is not to ignore kill signal, my goal is to execute some C functions before leaving my program" -- That's like wanting to do a few final things after you're dead. Kill means kill.

Comment: Ignoring the signal or catching it and executing your own code before it, is essentially the same thing. ;) So no, you can not do it.

Comment: @JimBalter kill with signal TERM (default signal sent by kill) allow the process to execute things

Comment: @MOHAMED Duh. Now please pay attention: You asked about "the kill signal", which is SIGKILL. The fact that the signal sending function is, for reasons of ancient history, called "kill" is not relevant. As has been noted repeatedly, you can't catch SIGKILL but you can catch other signals such as SIGTERM.